# Install a real-time kernel on CentOS

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

Recently I got to know about real time kernel. I just wanted to know how can I make my current CentOS 7.3 kernel into a real time kernel.

Kernel version I have is "3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64".

Answer (score 3):

If you're not experienced in patching your own kernel, install one of the stock real time kernels from a repository. One such option is to use the -ml series kernel from CERN.

To do so, first install the CERN-RT repo:

```
wget http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/rt/CentOS-RT.repo
yum groupinstall RT
```

This will install the RT kernel. Next:

```
reboot
```

After rebooting, you can then check the kernel version you're running like so:

```
uname -a
```

If you are NOT using the new kernel you just installed, you may need to adjust which kernel is set as default in /etc/default/grub. The GRUB_DEFAULT= points to the kernel image in use by numerical order. The first listed is 0, then 1, and so on. Once you've made sure that the correct number is listed, do:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Reboot again and verify that you're now on the correct kernel. More information on CERN kernels can be found here:

http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/rt/

Comment: Thanks for your response, it put me on the right track. However after the wget, you must still copy the CentOS-RT.repo file into your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory, and also copy the GPG contents from http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc5X/i386/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern into a file on your machine called   /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern

Comment: But if we need to add come config to kernel, how do we get its source code to make the change ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first add the CentOS real time repo:

```
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-rt.repo >/dev/null <<EOF
# CentOS-rt.repo

[rt]
name=CentOS-7 - rt
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/\$releasever/rt/\$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
EOF
```

Then install the rt-kernel and tuned profile:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y kernel-rt rt-tests tuned-profiles-realtime
sudo reboot
```

Note, though, that a real time kernel alone does not automatically give you optimal real time behavior. There are many knobs that would need tuning to achieve that, from BIOS level (e.g. disabling CPU power save, some SMI interrupts, etc.) to system level (CPU partitioning, IRQ balancing, etc.) to application level.

You can find some useful tuning tips in the [Advanced Tuning for RHEL for Real Time](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html-single/tuning_guide/) doc.

Comment: But if we need to add come config to kernel, how do we get its source code to make the change ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to configure anything real-time related in the kernel; only use tuned for that as described in the linked tuning guide.
If you need to change kernel configs for other reasons, you'll find the SRPMs as usual at http://vault.centos.org/.

Answer (score 3):

To install a specific version, one approach is to:

1. Add the CentOS-RT repository to yum
2. Download the exact kernel rpm file you require
3. Install the rpm via yum

---

For example, I needed to install kernel-rt-3.10.0-1062.12.1.rt56.1042, which can be found here: http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/rt/x86_64/Packages/

**Step 1**

You need to add the CentOS-RT repo to yum so that when you install the kernel rpm (step 3), yum knows where to find the dependencies.

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/rt/CentOS-RT.repo
```

**Step 2**

```
wget http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/rt/x86_64/Packages/kernel-rt-3.10.0-1062.12.1.rt56.1042.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

**Step 3**

```
yum -y install kernel-rt-3.10.0-1062.12.1.rt56.1042.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one solution when talking about real time linux kernel. If yiu read about the RT patch, the you should look here:

https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Rami Rosen