# Available options for real-time Linux (Centos 7) and their relation to one another

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, real-time

I'm looking to expand and also get more current information from the question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341933/install-a-real-time-kernel-on-centos).  I have a requirement for real-time behavior that has is sub-millisecond and am now exploring what my options are.  I am working with Centos, and ideally would be a more recent kernel (>4.14) for support for my chipset.  As I understand it, I have a few options:

- Apply the CONFIG_RT_PREEMPT patch to the kernel of my choice with the pre-emption model of my choice [(see here)](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- Utilize a canned real-time kernel from either [CERN](http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/rt/x86_64/Packages/) or [CENTOS](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.6.1810/rt/x86_64/Packages/), both of which top out at kernel version 3.10
- I'm also aware of a 'RTLinux' distro, which as I understand it is now a legacy product owned by WindRiver

So give the above knowledge, I've got a few questions:

1. Is the CERN site just a mirror for the CENTOS distribution?  They certainly look similar.  Who owns/maintains this?
2. Are the CERN and CENTOS real-time kernels just a canned flavor of the above CONFIG_RT_PREEMPT patch?
3. Just in case anyone on her has insight to the CONFIG_RT_PREEMPT patch, their main page lists their actively maintained kernel patches as (4.0-rt, 4.1-rt, 4.4-rt), although if you dig they've got patches available all the way up to 4.19, which is my preference.  What's their model for maintaining patches?  Why wouldn't I use the 4.19 patch?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you could contact your support group to get an answer. Cern has some pretty decent info about that I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel version 3.10 is the version RHEL 7.x (and so also CentOS and related distributions) is locked on. RedHat will maintain a version of that kernel and backport any necessary bugfixes and new drivers as part of the active support for their distribution. When RHEL 8.0 will be released, it will have a new kernel version that will again be maintained for the duration of the 8.x series. Since the kernel source code is open, CentOS and other related distributions get to use the same extremely widely used (and so extensively tested) code base.

1.) CERN, the European Organization for Nuclear Research, [maintains a version of CentOS 7 with optional customizations specifically for use at CERN.](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/centos7/)

2.) Canned by RedHat and supported by them in RHEL 7.x with backported bugfixes and other things, yes. Because these kernels are the basis of RHEL 7.x, they get to benefit from all the things backported by RedHat, so they might actually have significantly better support for new hardware than Linus Torvalds's "vanilla" 3.10.

3.) You can think of it as a continuum between "enterprise-grade" 3.10 in RHEL/CentOS, and the "bleeding edge" of... actually kernel version 5.0.7 at the time of this writing. I don't really know about their maintaining model.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the rhel 7.x to v3.10 kernel was what I was missing. Do you have any insight as to whether the RT CentOs kernels are the same/similar to the standard RHEL kernel with the CONFIG_RT_PREEMT patch applied, or are they not related? Thanks

Comment: Yes, RHEL 7.x includes a kernel-rt package, which is the RHEL standard kernel with the RT patch applied (with maybe some secondary modifications if required to match the backports in the RHEL kernel), and CentOS (and also CERN) just duplicates that.